# Common base configuration

Tags: power-supply, transistors, common-base, circuitlab

I have tried to implement this circuit of common base configuration but the power supply used in the lab is very confusing and I suspect it’s the reason why my readings aren’t turning out right (it’s the GWINSTEK GPC-3060D) a dual bench power supply , what mode exactly do i set the input and output supply to? Is it parallel since they’ve in fact parallel in the circuit?

[image]

Comment: What kind of readings ? Could you list in a array ?

Comment: Note that the VEE supply has to be negative. So the supplies are not in parallel.

Comment: On that power supply, you will have to press buttons to put dual supplies in series.  One supply will be negative, the other positive.  And we need to see your measurements.